# How should I parse 整个候选人赛14盘比赛?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

In (international) chess news regarding next year's word championship:

> **整个候选人赛14盘比赛**，丁立人低开高走，前8盘战绩仅为1负7和，后6盘则是4胜1和1负。
> <sub>孙海光, [首获男子国象世界冠军战资格，丁立人有信心捅破“窗户纸”丨专访](https://m.bjnews.com.cn/detail/1663210856168480.html), September 2022.</sub>

It's referring to the [candidates tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidates_Tournament_2022) and how the Chinese player 丁立人 came second after a comeback.

In the above, I'm wondering if I should parse 整个候选人赛14盘比赛 as:

- all [整个] candidates [候选人] competed in [赛] a 14-round competition [14盘比赛]; or
- the whole [整个] candidates tournament [候选人赛] comprised of a 14-round competition [14盘比赛].

Basically, this boils down to whether or not 候选人赛 is interpreted as "candidates tournament" or "candidates compete".  While I feel 整个 would be better matched with interpreting 候选人赛 as a noun "candidates tournament", the clause seems to lack a verb in that interpretation (something equivalent to "comprised of").

**Question**: How should I parse 整个候选人赛14盘比赛?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 整个 - The entire
- 候选人赛 - Candidates Tournament
- 14盘比赛 - 14 games

1. 

> (在)整个候选人赛(的)14盘比赛(中)

> (In) the entire Candidates Tournament('s) 14 games

丁立人低开高走，前8盘战绩仅为1负7和，后6盘则是4胜1和1负。

丁立人 started slow and finished strong, with no win, 7 draws, and 1 loss in the first 8 games; then 4 wins, 1 draw, and 1 loss in the last 6 games.

*He finished with 4 wins, 8 draws, and 2 losses*

2.

> 整个候选人赛(有)14盘比赛

> The entire Candidates Tournament (has) 14 games

#1 tightly connects with the game results that followed

#2 is a stand-alone sentence

Answer (score 1):

When 整个 is used, it refers to "things","matters", "events". Thus 整个 refers to the "tournament", and not the "candidates" themselves.

When it refers to "people", ("candidates"), 所有 is used. Thus if it is supposed to be "All candidates competed in....", it would have been "所有候选人都参加...."

The correct parse is the 2nd choice.

Answer (score 1):

整个 is "all", but it is not quantify the candidate but the "games".

**整个**(候选人赛)**14盘比赛** - All 14 games of the candidate's tournament.

Answer (score 0):

Change 整 for 每

整个候选人赛14盘比赛，
每个候选人赛14盘比赛,
Each competitor competed in 14 games,